# How to use a USB card reader on linux VM using Hyper-V and VMconnect?

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Microsoft has a site about "Use local resources on Hyper-V virtual machine with VMConnect" but nothing for linux VM. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/learn-more/use-local-resources-on-hyper-v-virtual-machine-with-vmconnect

I got a usb card reader thats not working in Linux mint VM, how do i get it to work??

Comment: You need to use enhanced mode, see: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2018/02/28/sneak-peek-taking-a-spin-with-enhanced-linux-vms/  and https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/09/17/run-ubuntu-virtual-machines-made-even-easier-with-hyper-v-quick-create/

Comment: enhanced mode doesnt work with linux mint, right now im starting a new VM using ubuntu through Quick install because that might have enhanced mode.